# Explode array to multi array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my default array and this concat_group will explode in my code

**MySQL CODE**
this is my query to get data

```
SELECT
    results.StuID,
    subjects_d.SubjectID,
    subjects.ID,
    users.*,
    exams.ID,
    classes.Name AS ClName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.Super_Degree, ',',subjects_d.SubjectID, ',', results.ExamID, ',',results.Exam1,',',results.Exam2,',',results.Exam3 ORDER BY subjects_d.SubjectID, results.ExamID  ASC) AS data
FROM
    results
LEFT JOIN
    users
ON 
    users.UID = results.StuID
LEFT JOIN
    subjects_d
ON
    subjects_d.SubID = results.Sub_ID
LEFT JOIN
    subjects
ON
    subjects_d.SubjectID = subjects.ID
LEFT JOIN
    exams
ON 
    exams.ID = results.ExamID
INNER JOIN
    classes
ON 
    classes.CID = subjects_d.C_ID
WHERE 
    subjects_d.C_ID = ?
GROUP BY results.StuID
ORDER BY StuID
```

**PHP CODE**
here I want to explode my array from MySQL

```
<?php foreach ($arr as $student) {
    <?php $data_array = explode(',',$student['data']); ?>
    <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($data_array) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**OUTPUT**
the output from print_r.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 90
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 90
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 90
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 0 
}
```

I need to Explode this to multi-array like it

**Need to get this output**

```
Array[0]
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 90
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
Array[1]
    (
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 90
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
)
Array[2]
    (
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 90
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 0 
)
```

need your help to get this output arrays

**Thank you.**

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and can cause invalid data... https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk` for this.

```
$final = array_chunk( $arr, 5, true );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 90
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 90
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [10] => 3
            [11] => 90
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 0
        )

)
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php